# Access Synology Over VPN On Separate Subnet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing

I have a synology disk station and it's hosting their moments photo backup application. I'm trying to access Synology Moments remotely via a VPN.

The disk station can host a VPN, so I set up an L2TP VPN. I placed all hosts on IP addresses 192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.200

What I'd like to do is once connected to the VPN, access hosts on the 192.168.1.0 subset, specifically I want to access the diskstation using the 192.168.1.0 subset. It's IP is 192.168.1.15. This way I can use the same IP address when I am on the VPN or home on my network.

So I set up a static routing table on my linksys router: Destination: 192.168.2.0 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.1.15

And yet this does not seem to be working. I can only access the diskstation on the 192.168.2.0 subnet, the subnet assigned to hosts on the VPN.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: so you are expecting the synology to act as a router between the VPN gateway subnet (.2.0) and the main subnet (.1.0) and back again. correct?

Comment: I suppose so. I separately have an independent linksys router. That's where I entered the static routing information. I'd sooner prefer the linksys router handle all routing functions but I'm not certain if that's possible or the VPN host (the synology) needs to also have this function.

Comment: ok so the device you are VPN'ing into isn't the device routing the .2.0 network, and isn't even inside the .2.0 network? yeah that's not going to work if I'm understanding you correctly. the VPN clients will only reach the gateway device (the nas) and if the gateway cannot provide routing to the clients to reach other internal devices, nothing else can. usually if you want to drop a VPN gateway into the middle of a network, you would use iptables to provide NAT masquerading to forward traffic from the gateway onto the lan.

Comment: Would I establish a static route on my NAS to bridge the .2.0 with the .1.0 subnet?

Comment: actually I don;t think you need to. Take the linksys out of the equation, and when you configure the VPN server, there is a box to tick called 'Allow clients to access server's LAN'. checking it should allow the behavior you want. see instructions for VPN Server configuration here: https://www.synology.com/cgi/knowledgebase/findHelpFile/dsm/VPNCenter/1.2/enu/5.2-5644/synology_avoton_415+/100/vpn_setup.html